# Esconder parametro do ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Por exemplo: `/admin/Edit/1006` Há alguma forma de esconder esse id? Pois assim qualquer usuário mal intencionado pode alterar o valor e acabar achando um usuário. Eu sei que deve-se fazer uma verificação no controller para saber se o usuário pode ou não editar, mas falando só do ActionLink. Há alguma forma de esconder isso? Ou pelo menos "dificultar" a vida do individuo que estiver tentando acessar dados que ele não tem permissão. Pensei em utilizar GUID, mas o URL fica muito grande. Existe algum padrão, ou recomendação sobre os parametros do ActionLink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem algumas técnicas que você pode usar.

1. Usar um *slug*;
2. Usar um localizador;
3. Usar outra maneira de localizar unicamente o registro, como um Id gerado.

## *Slug*

*Slug* é um identificador descritivo do registro. Por exemplo, esta pergunta tem como *slug* `esconder-parametro-do-actionlink`. O problema é que pra isso funcionar corretamente o sistema deve garantir que este identificador é único. Repare que até aqui no SO usa-se um *slug* composto de Id + descrição.

Implementar uma rota baseada em *slug* exige uma reimplementação do `MvcRouteHandler` e registrá-lo na tabela de rotas. [Essa resposta ensina como fazer isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611863/net-mvc-4-routing-with-custom-slugs).

## Localizador

Uma outra tática é gerar um localizador para o registro, composto de uma `string` randômica de pelo menos 6 caracteres (assim como os localizadores de voos e passagens viárias, por exemplo). Neste caso, bastaria parametrizar a `Action` com um localizador e tratar localizadores inválidos.

```
public ActionResult PesquisarPorLocalizador(String localizador)
{
    var registro = contexto.Registros.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Localizador == localizador);
    if (registro == null) return View("NotFound");

    // Restante da lógica
}
```

## Identificador Externo

Outra maneira seria gerar "um segundo Id" para cada registro, seguindo alguma ordem ou normativa. A solução é muito parecida com a solução por localizador. A `Action` receberia como parâmetro esse Id externo, preservando o Id interno do registro.

Comment: Obrigado. Acho que o localizador e uma verificação no controller deve ser o suficiente.