# Ocultar parâmetro URL no MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Como ocultar o parâmetro Id da URL utilizando rotas ou máscara?

```
PessoaFisica/Edit/1
```

para

```
PessoaFisica/Edit


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou discutir na resposta algumas formas e recomendar uma.

## 1. Usando *slugs* (recomendado)

Falo disso nestas respostas:

- [Montar URL sem aparecer o nome da Action ou da Controller ou ambas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9805/montar-url-sem-aparecer-o-nome-da-action-ou-da-controller-ou-ambas/9806?s=1|0.3716#9806)
- [Esconder parametro do ActionLink](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45774/esconder-parametro-do-actionlink/45776?s=2|0.3641#45776)
- [Roteamento e Url amigáveis com asp.net mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82091/roteamento-e-url-amig%c3%a1veis-com-asp-net-mvc/82500?s=3|0.3106#82500)

O princípio é usar outro parâmetro para identificar a pessoa e passá-lo na rota. O CPF, por exemplo, é um bom candidato. O nome pode ser outro candidato, mas aí é preciso escolher alguma forma de desfazer ambiguidades em caso de duplicidade de nomes.

## 2. Usando `POST`

Esta não é uma boa forma porque, para acessar um registro, você sempre precisará submeter um formulário, validá-lo, para só assim encaminhar o usuário para a tela de edição.

## 3. Usando uma variável codificada

Esta lembra o método 1, mas implica em alguma implementação a mais. A ideia é uma URL assim:

```
/PessoaFisica/Acao/?codigo=A2B7649C100DB2F641
```

Utilizando algum algoritmo de criptografia reversível, você consegue mascarar o Id e a ação a ser executada dentro da variável criptografada.

Apesar de funcionar, é mais desvantajosa que o *slug* por não ser intuitiva.

Comment: Ok amigo! Vou utilizar a opção 3 mesmo. Pensei em utilizar Guid mas não fica usual no banco!